# AudioTrack Session Disabled

Tags: ios, webrtc, quickblox, avaudiosession, audiotrack

I'm using the QuickBlox RTC Api, and I can enable and disable the AudioTrack using the following command:

```
[self.session.localMediaStream.audioTrack setEnabled:NO];
```

But when I also set the AVAudioSession to 'NO':

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[audioSession setActive:NO error:nil];
```

For some reason I can't get the AudioTrack anymore back.

Is it possible to do get it back and reactivate as many times as I want?

Thanks!

Comment: Anyone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is no possible way to deactivate AVAudioSession without audioTrack being deinitialized for now. There is investigating in progress but no any ETA for the new version yet.

Comment: Thanks on your reply!

Is there any way to mute it or put it on hold?

Comment: Just set audioTrack enabled no.